# variable to a query

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I got this code: 
...

```
Dim contP as String ="0"
Dim LeftJIF as String =""
sqlquery =("select CLas1, CLas2, CLas3"+ContP+" 
                from CLas" + LeftJIF )

            Using connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("server=" & srvSQL & ";database=" & bdSQL & ";uid=" & usrSQL & ";password=" & pswSQL & ";")
              connection.Open()
                Using com As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlquery, connection)
                    Dim rs As SqlDataReader = com.ExecuteReader
                    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
                    dt.Load(rs)

                    ''Here I'm trying to do what's below. 


                    Call clCreateCSV.CreateCSVFile(dt, strFileName)
                End Using 

                    connection.Close()
            End Using
```

So, for each result on the query I need to fill the variable ContP with data coming from a left join. IF the field "CLas3" from each one is "472" or "477" it will assign a table field and the left join acordingly

I was thinking in something like this just following dt.Load(rs)

```
                    For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows

                        If dt.Rows(0).Item("CLas3") = "472" Then

                            ContP = "clients.client3"
                            leftJoinsif = "left join InvoiceS on CLas4 = InvoiceS.invoice4
                                                " + "left join clients on InvoiceS.invoice5 = clients.client1"

                        ElseIf dt.Rows(0).Item("CLas3") = "477" Then
                            ContP = "providers.provider3"
                            leftJoinsif = "left join InvoiceV on CLas4 = InvoiceV.invoice4
                                                " + "left join providers on InvoiceV.invoice5 = providers.provider1"

                        Else
                            contP = ""
                            leftJoinsif = ""

                        End If

                    Next
```

The tables look like this, just in case is needed.

```
CLas
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
CLas1 | Clas2 | CLas3 | Clas4
10      R       472     I1
10      S       600     I1
10      N       129
20      S       700     I2
20      R       472     I2
...

InvoiceS
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

invoice1 | invoice2 | invoice3 | invoice4 | invoice5
    001         x       y           I1      000001
    002         x       y           I2      000002
    ...

clients
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
client1 | client2 | client3
000001      name    V
000002      name    C
...
```

So, after all the query should result in something like:

```
10,R,472,V
10,S,600,
10,N,129,
20,S,700,
20,R,472,C
```

All in all, it's failing, not retrieving anything. Tested the query separately on a sql server and seems to be working. I'm not sure if there is an easier way to do this or if I can operate with the dt rows on that state(Still not quite understand it yet)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"It's failing, not retrieving anything"_ is not a very useful problem description.  This problem is too high-level with too many potential points of failure for anyone to effectively diagnose via an online Q&A post.  You need to spend some time attempting to diagnose which part is actually failing before anyone could hope to help you figure out why.

Comment: Yes, sorry. The first thing is I'm not sure if this is the correct way to work with a dt, or even if i'm doing it right since I'm an starter. Seems it's actually failing here `If dt.Rows(0).Item("CLas3") = "472" Then` with "the row CLas3 doesn't belong to the table", but I cant see why since *I think*, i'm inside the dt already. Is this the correct way to work with data on a dt? Is there any easier way to do this? what am I doing wrong? :) Thanks